# Try to play MP3 audio file with NAudio

Tags: c#, .net, mp3, naudio, lame

I'm following [this tutorial](http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MP3) to play MP3 audio files with NAudio. To create the WaveStream I use this method:

```
private WaveStream CreateInputStream(string fileName)
        {
            WaveChannel32 inputStream;
            if (fileName.EndsWith(".mp3"))
            {
                WaveStream mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(fileName);
                inputStream = new WaveChannel32(mp3Reader);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported extension");
            }
            volumeStream = inputStream;
            return volumeStream;
        }
```

Unfortunately I always get an exception in the

```
line inputStream = new WaveChanne32(mp3Reader):
```

> Blockquote

```
System.ApplicationException was unhandled
  Message=Only PCM supported
  Source=NAudio
  StackTrace:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var pStream = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(mp3Reader);
var inputStream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

PCM is an encoding type (Pulse-code modulation). Seems like NAudio can only handle PCM encoded files.

Comment: Thanks. And how do I ensure that the file I'm playing is PCM encoded? I encode the MP3 file that I'm trying to play here by myself using Lame

Comment: I had a look at that example... and I find that very strange. As far as I know a MP3 file is never PCM encoded. So that piece of code cannot work... I think... I'm not a music format specialist, just a programmer who happens to play guitar.

Comment: this is not true. NAudio has the MP3FileReader class that can handle MP3 files. The issue is that the WaveChannel32 class takes PCM as an input. i.e. you need to convert MP3 to PCM before passing in to WaveStream32.